# compiling kivy app to apk fail using python-for-android

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk, mobile-application

i wrote a hello world test app with python and kivy, and try to package it into apk but it has been showing me this error and i don't understand what's going on.

This is my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text = 'Hello World')

if __name__ in ('__android__', '__main__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

And i try to compile to apk using this command:

```
p4a apk --private ./ --package=org.example.easample --name "easample" --version 0.1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,pygame
```

It gives this error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req, self.session, self.finder, self.require_hashes
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 224, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 49, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 39, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self.req.prepare_metadata()
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 563, in prepare_metadata
    self.metadata_directory = metadata_generator(self)
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/generate_metadata.py", line 124, in _generate_metadata_legacy
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info',
  File "/home/ea/.local/share/python-for-android/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.


  STDERR:
```

Pls i need help

Comment: Did you tried using Buildozer in Ubuntu?

Comment: no i haven't. i will try that now.

Comment: Which OS are you using to compile

Comment: Don't use pygame, take it out of the requirements.

Comment: i'm on ubuntu. @inclement i will take it out now